# Will a US, Asia, and Europe CDN improve page load time for Central American visitors to a US hosted site?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, cdn

The CDN's location  servers are on US, Europe, and Asia.  The web page is hosted in US. Visitors to your website are only from Central America.

Will the website page load time be benefit if that CDN is used?

Comment: CDN's distribute your website content throughout a network of servers, and many will serve the requests for it from the nearest server (e.g., CloudFlare). Even if the CDN only serves content from the countries you specified (I'd suggest confirming that), they'll still route traffic to the least busy location, so the answer is yes, depending on the quality of the CDN service of course.

Comment: Why aren't you looking into a CDN or a host in Central America?

Comment: Why is this phrased like a homework question?

Comment: as far as I know, the CDN's are from those countries only , and I think Amazon have one in SOuth America. But i am happy with dan's explanation.

Comment: Apart from the distribution benefits offered by many CDNs who have many points of presence (POP) as mentioned by Dan, a CDN's other main purpose is to take load away from the primary server and are optimised to serve static resources, so speeding up the load time in the browser relative to the user's own internet connection. So, yes, a US-located CDN is more than likely going to provide a decent speed advantage to load time for US visitors.